# Magento2 - How to show a block content on homepage

Tags: magento2, cms-block, home

**How to show a block content on homepage?**

After install magento2 without sample data, I chose 'Magento Luma' theme and add 'Home Page Block' block and copy the code from the sample store.

but nothing show up on the home page, how to show my cms block on home page like sample store?

my home
[image]

sample store

[image]

Comment: You mean showing custom cms block text/content or admin panel created cms block text/content?

Comment: @magentotwo I create a custom cms block I want to know how to show this blcok on home page

Comment: have you tried below solution?

Comment: The home page content in sample data is coming from widgets.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

in admin panel go to Content->Pages and edit home page and if you created your static block from admin panel add following to the Content tab

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="your_block_identifier"}}
```

and if you created a custom block using a module add following to home page content tab

```
{{block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" template="Vendor_ModuleName::yourcustomblock.phtml"}}
```

then save the changes and flush magento cache and deploy/delete static contents
now refresh home page .

If this was not worked let me know

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks a lot Chamal!

Comment: Is there any link I can learn more about this? magento block class and block id code for front-end?

Comment: I found http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/frontend/front-layout.html this is a good guide for understanding magento 2 block architecture

Comment: From my module's `cms_index_index.xml`, I added this in Home Page content - `<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index"  name="modulename" template="module.phtml"></block> and 
It says `Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Module::module.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'index_0'``

Comment: ifconfig is not working with this approach. Any idea ?

Answer (score 10):

try this or else post your code then we will suggest you where you went wrong.

**Block file**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\SmartSearch\Block;

class SmartSearch extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return "Smart Search";
    }
}
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_SmartSearch" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**view/layout/cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Learning\SmartSearch\Block\SmartSearch" template="Learning_SmartSearch::html/cms.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/templates/html/cms.phtml**

```
<h1><?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?></h1>
```

after creating flush cache.

I hope this will help you. If you are not getting results let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try later and let you know the result

Answer (score 3):

In the home page you can call the static block like the below mentioned way

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="your_block_identifier"}}
```

In the html page you can call the static block like the below mentioned way.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```