# In magento2 after installation and setting luma as default template why there is no blocks and images in frontend end

Tags: magento2

I did complete installation backend is good but frontend doesnt load images and blocks [image]. Whats the reason for it
Backend is working preety fine[image]
Need some help

Comment: I see you are a new user, please [accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem. You can do this by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 with Luma looks like this out of the box when you don't have sample data installed or any content added yet.

If you want to change this you can do any of these:

- [Install sample data](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html)
- [Add CMS blocks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95082/magento2-how-to-show-a-block-content-on-homepage)
- [Add Categories](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/product-categories)