# How do I insert a block from a phtml file on magento 2.0 admin?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, phtml, custom-block

I have an index file on my server and I am trying to get it to show the contents on my site by linking it on the homepage through the admin.

In Magento 1, I did it like this and it worked:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/default/carousel/index.phtml"}}
```

How can I write this on Magento 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

```
{{block class="Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template" template="Vendor_Module::default/carousel/index.phtml"}}
```

See more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95551/33057

Comment: Tried it but that didn't work. Is there any specific location I should put my phtml file?

Comment: For example, you have a custom module: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/default/carousel/index.phtml`.

Comment: @DevAnd Did you have a custom module?

Comment: I have a folder with my index, css, and assets. Don't know whwere to place that within my magento server.

Comment: Yeah! Need to learn a lot of things: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/ and http://devdocs.magento.com/

Comment: I think their might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: @DevAnd you should try another way.